# In LyX, how do you remove the brackets around a matrix after they're already there?

Tags: lyx, matrices, arrays, brackets, wysiwyg

I used the GUI to make a matrix with round brackets, and now I want to remove the round brackets (or change them to square brackets), how do I do that?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible. If you don't get a response, you might want to open an enhancement request on https://www.lyx.org/trac

Answer (score 3):

A very dirty workaround.

Suppose you have `myfile.lyx`:

[image]

Save it as `myfile2.lyx` to have a backup in case of error.

Close LyX and open `myfile.lyx` with a text editor (like Notepad++ or similar), you'll have this:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
I want this without round brackets: 
\begin_inset Formula 
\[
\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
I want this with square brackets: 
\begin_inset Formula 
\[
\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Now change `pmatrix` with `array` if you don't want brackets or `pmatrix` with `bmatrix` if you want square brackets, you'll get this:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
I want this without round brackets: 
\begin_inset Formula 
\[
\begin{array}a & b\\% <-- changed
c & d
\end{array}% <-- changed
\]

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
I want this with square brackets: 
\begin_inset Formula 
\[
\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\% <-- changed
c & d
\end{bmatrix}% <-- changed
\]

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Save it and close the text editor.

Open it with LyX, et voilà:

[image]

*Pay attention: do not change anything else, unless you know what you're doing, and always make a backup copy of your `.lyx` document before doing these things.*

Comment: Well in that case, just highlight the matrix in the LyX GUI, copy, paste into a text editor, and edit "pmatrix" to "matrix" or "bmatrix", then paste back into the LyX GUI.

Comment: @user1271772 Yes, of course, but you have to use ERT

Comment: No you don't, I just did it, it was fine.

Comment: @user1271772 Good, I didn't think you could paste LaTeX code into LyX without ERT

Comment: In recent versions of LyX, as long as you first do CTRL+M to get a math box, or there's a mathbox already there (as in the case where we had a pmatrix that we wanted to replace with a bmatrix), if you copy and paste any latex code, it should automatically show up as LyX formatted math :)

Comment: @user1271772 Good to know. I didn't usually use LyX but I'm pleased to know the existence of this feature :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Highlight the matrix in the LyX GUI.
2. Copy and paste it into a text editor.
3. Edit "pmatrix" to "matrix" (no brackets) or "bmatrix" (square brackets),
4. Paste back into the LyX GUI.

Answer (score 1):

With version 2.3.7 it's perfectly possible to copy-paste the elements of a matrix like any other objects.

---

Let's use this matrix:

[image]

1. Select the elements by clicking inside the matrix, then using `Ctrl-a` once or twice (the first selects the row, the second all rows, but sometimes all elements are selected at once):

   [image]

   Note the brackets are not selected.
2. Send the selection to the clipboard (`Ctrl-c`).
3. Create a new matrix using `Insert|Math|Matrix...` choose the appropriate size and alignment, and set `Decoration Type` to any value, e.g. choose `None` if you want to remove the brackets:

   [image]
4. Click in the first element, to set the start of the coming paste.
5. Paste (`Ctrl-v`):

   [image]

You could use this procedure as well to copy only some elements, and possibly paste them elsewhere into the same matrix.